# Find the indicated probability.

Tags: probability, statistics

Question: In a batch of 8,000 clock radios 2% are defective. A sample of 11 clocks is randomly selected without replacement from the 8,000 tested. The entire batch will be rejected if at least one of those 11 selected is defective. What is the probability that the entire batch will be rejected?

What is the formula to use for these type of problems and how do I solve it?
So far I figured that 2% of 8,000 is 160, so there are 7840 good clocks.

Comment: The probability that at least one clock is defective = 1 - probability that no clock is defective. Surely you know how to do this. What's the chance that if you pick one clock, it's not defective. What about picking two? Three...

Comment: From a practical point of view, the sampling without replacement of this problem gives an answer not much different from sampling with replacement. So the probability the entire lot will be rejected is approximately $1-(0.98)^{11}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, we can use a technique called complementary counting. The basic idea is that

(probability of event A) = 1 - (probability of not A)

or

$$P(A) = 1 - P(not \space A)$$

We can use this here.  Event A is that the clock is defective, so Event (not A) means the clock works.

$$0.02 = 1 - P(not \space A)$$

$$P(not \space A) = 0.98$$

Therefore, for all the clocks to pass, the probability is $P(not \space A)^{11}$.

Now again, we can use complementary counting.

(probability of all clocks failing) = 1 - (probability of all clocks passing)

Probability of all clocks failing = $1-P(not \space A)^{11}$

Answer (score 0):

One way to compute this is to instead compute the probability that the entire batch will pass. To compute that probability, we need to find the probability that all eleven clocks will not be defective. The probability for the first clock is obviously 98%. However, you must adjust that probability for the later clocks in the sample, because now there is one less good clock (and the same number of bad clocks) in the sample. You need only multiply these probabilities together to get the probability that the batch will pass, and it is simple to get the probability of the batch not passing from there.